# How to get the index of current item of all items in Tableview from SearchBar

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar

I'm trying to delete an item from Tableview, everything works fine if the SearchBar is empty, (indexPath is the right index) . but if i'm using SearchBar  i get the index of filtered item .

How to get the current index of an item from Tableview? but after filtering with SearchBar.

```
 func filterTableView(ind:Int,text:String) {
        switch ind {
        case selectedScope.reviewDate.rawValue:
            filteredDays = ViewController.reviewDaysArr.filter({ (mod) -> Bool in
                return mod.reviewDate.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
            })
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        case selectedScope.reviewPlace.rawValue:
            filteredDays = ViewController.reviewDaysArr.filter({ (mod) -> Bool in
                return mod.reviewPlace.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
            })
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        case selectedScope.reviewSum.rawValue:
            filteredDays = ViewController.reviewDaysArr.filter({ (mod) -> Bool in
                return mod.reviewSum.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
            })
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }


static var reviewDaysArr:[ReviewDay] = [

    ReviewDay(reviewDate: "03/03/2017", reviewPlace: "Manhattan"),
    ReviewDay(reviewDate: "03/03/2017", reviewPlace: "Manhattan"),
    ReviewDay(reviewDate: "05/03/2017", reviewPlace: "New Jersey")

]

var filteredDays = reviewDaysArr

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        ViewController.reviewDaysArr.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        filteredDays = ViewController.reviewDaysArr
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Comment: filter the main array than reload your table view

Comment: Also add the code of  how you are filtering your data.

Comment: @NiravD done...

Comment: @MarryG Ok let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index of your main Array from your filtered array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        //First check using your condition that is search active 
        if searchActive {
            //I'm comparing movieId you can compare any unique property of your Movie class
            if let index = ViewController.dataArr.index(where: {$0.movieId == filterdData[indexPath.row].movieId}) {
                //Remove object from mainArray
                ViewController.dataArr.remove(at: index)
                //Remove object from filtered array
                filterdData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            }
        }
        else {
            ViewController.dataArr.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

**Edit:** As of you are not having any unique property with your model class `Movie` there is only one way to get the index of object. You need to get the array of indices for filtered array correspond to the main array. So declare one array of type `[Int]` and after filtering your array get the filter object index in that array.

```
var filterIndices = [Int]()
```

Now where you are filtering the array initialized this array also.

```
switch ind {
    case selectedScope.reviewDate.rawValue:
        filteredDays = ViewController.reviewDaysArr.filter({ (mod) -> Bool in
            return mod.reviewDate.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
        })
        filterIndices = ViewController.reviewDaysArr.indices.filter({
            ViewController.reviewDaysArr[$0].reviewDate.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()) 
        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    case selectedScope.reviewPlace.rawValue:
        filteredDays = ViewController.reviewDaysArr.filter({ (mod) -> Bool in
            return mod.reviewPlace.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
        })
        filterIndices = ViewController.reviewDaysArr.indices.filter({
            ViewController.reviewDaysArr[$0].reviewPlace.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()) 
        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    case selectedScope.reviewSum.rawValue:
        filteredDays = ViewController.reviewDaysArr.filter({ (mod) -> Bool in
            return mod.reviewSum.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
        })
        filterIndices = ViewController.reviewDaysArr.indices.filter({
            ViewController.reviewDaysArr[$0].reviewSum.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()) 
        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now in `commit editingStyle` get this index form array and delete the object from both main and filter array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        //First check using your condition that is search active 
        if searchActive {
            //Remove object from mainArray using filterIndices
            ViewController.reviewDaysArr.remove(at: filterIndices[indexPath.row])
            //Remove object from filtered array
            filteredDays.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
        else {
            ViewController.reviewDaysArr.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarryG Then you can use movie name that you are showing in your cell

Comment: In my case, I don't have any movieID or something unique to that object. the screenshots just for explain my point.
in my object, I have only dates of meeting and places, but this is not unique ...